# Social Bookmarking using ShareThis : javascript error 'SHARETHIS is undefined'

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting "SHARETHIS is undefined" in a page where I used ShareThis social bookmarking utility. Here is my code

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Demo</TITLE>

  <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'f5b1585e-488a-403c-8b7e-ade3efab880a'});</script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <span class='st_sharethis' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        SHARETHIS.addEntry({
            url:'http://www.google.com'
        }, {button:true} );
    </script>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Can anyone please tell me what could be the problem and how to resolve?

Thanks, 
Amit Patel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inspected the DOM using Firebug. No variable named `SHARETHIS`. However, there is a variable named `stWidget` which has a function `addEntry`. I replaced `SHARETHIS` with `stWidget` and there were no errors. I dont know the correct behavior of the widget, but there is no error.

EDIT: Changed the code to share google.com instead of current url.

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Demo</TITLE>

  <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'f5b1585e-488a-403c-8b7e-ade3efab880a'});</script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <span class='st_sharethis' st_url="http://www.google.com" st_title="Google" displayText="Share This"></span>  
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks Aravindan. Now error gone. But the functionality is not working as expected. It should share google.com instead sharing current page.

Comment: Please look at the API in ShareThis.com site.. http://help.sharethis.com/customization/share-properties  You need to change your span tag.

Comment: changed code to share google.com. Please "Accept" the answer if it works.